# Unit testing for Javascript

Tags: unit-testing

Can any one tell me is it possible to create nunit test case for javascript and jquery? if it is possible how to unit test the javascript and jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Qunit testing library to test your javascript and jQuery..

http://qunitjs.com/

You can also use [FireUnit](http://ejohn.org/blog/fireunit/)  , a firebug extension to unit test your javasvript..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you need, but I test my Javascript with this site: http://jsfiddle.net/
You can put in the code and execute to see the results.